# Restrict Shield UI chart slice selection to one slice (via Wicket)

Tags: javascript, charts, wicket, wicket-6, shieldui

Is there way to restrict Shield UI pie charts via the Wicket API (although it's not clear that you can do this with the raw JavaScript API either) in such a way that only allows one slice to be selected at a time?

If there's no way to do this via the API, is it possible to intercept the shift click and transform it into a standard click before it gets processed by the Shield UI JS?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the dev team, they have made changes to the Javascript and the Wicket API code to allow this to happen.

```
chart.getOptions().getSeriesSettings().getPie().setAllowMultiPointSelection(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the selection mechanism of the chart is single. This is demonstrated in the following example:
https://demos.shieldui.com/web/pie-chart/sliced-offset
Another option would be to disable the default selection and simply allow clicking and then try to set the .selected property of a the corresponding datapoint.

Comment: In the linked-to example it is still possible to shift-click another slice while one slice is already selected, resulting in 2 selected slices. I need to force only one slice selected at a time. Also, I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the slicedOffset property for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no easy way to force selection of 0 or 1 slices at a time. Currently selecting while pressing the Shift / Ctrl keys will not unselect the other slices.

You might want to contact their support and ask their opinion/solution on your request.